# What's the arcade game Kate and Dade play in the movie Hackers?

Tags: game-identification

Near the beginning of the movie *Hackers*, Kate and Dade play an arcade game involving ships flying down a trench, avoiding moving walls and shooting at enemy turrets. The game was controlled with dual joysticks.

Does this game exist as an arcade machine or other platform game around that time (1995)? If it's purely for show, is it inspired by any popular arcade titles from the same era?

Here's a screenshot for nostalgia:

[image: Dade about to beat the high score]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, I always thought that the game was made up just for the movie, but it turns out it was an early version of [Wipeout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wipeout_%28video_game%29),  which was released later that year (Sept '95).

Who knew?

Also: [citations](http://koldfusion.ca/wp/2007/06/trivia-for-hackers-the-movie/), [cite](http://www.epinions.com/review/mvie_mu-1064439/content_260372205188), [cite](http://ask.metafilter.com/17369/Video-Game-from-Hackers), [cite](http://wiki.docdroppers.org/index.php?title=Hackers_%28movie%29), [cite](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113243/trivia?tr=tr0772680).

Comment: Gah, beaten to the punch. Was about to post http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113243/trivia?tr=tr0772680. Well played sir.

Comment: I totally feel embarrassed for having been about to post that it was a CGI movie.

Answer (score 2):

And did you know that they don't even play it !

@Mana you are right because it's a CGI movie that emulate a fake gameplay

Proof:

This is the actual gameplay video made by the guy who was working on the project that year.

Comment: Just because it's prerecorded for the film doesn't mean that it wasn't recorded play of an actual game, as @tzenes citations suggest. I don't think we'll ever know for sure, unless someone who worked on the project came here and told us.

Comment: This is not an actual play, it's just a movie concept of the game that they used for the movie. If you look at the comment of the video in question, you'll notice that the guy was working for Psygnosis and was part of the project. That's why he have that video !

Comment: I see the comment that suggests jona76 worked on the project, but I don't see anything stating that it was a "movie concept of a game". Where did you find that information?

Comment: The game being played in the arcade is a high-quality prototype of the Playstation game “Wipeout” by Psygnosis. It is done on a high-end SGI server and allowed the development team to try out tracks and gameplay, before porting it to the Playstation. - http://koldfusion.ca/wp/2007/06/trivia-for-hackers-the-movie/

Comment: Exactly. That's what the other answer says.

Comment: Anyway I could get a little +1 for finding the original video no :P